# using an input variable in multiple functions in python

Tags: python, function, variables, input

I would like to know how to use the 'name' variable in the `entername()` function in the `hello()` function.

It is an input variable, does anyone know how to use it across multiple functions?

```
def entername():
    name = input("Please enter your name: ")
    return

def hello():
    text = "Hello " + name + ", welcome to the simulator..."
    for char in text:
        sys.stdout.write(char)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        char, time.sleep(0.1)
    print(char)  
    return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a variable defined in the scope of a function, inside another function. You could, however, return the name value, and pass it as a parameter to the next function:

```
import sys, time

def entername():
    name = input("Please enter your name: ")
    return name

def hello(name):
    text = "Hello " + name + ", welcome to the simulator..."
    for char in text:
        sys.stdout.write(char)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        char, time.sleep(0.1)
    print(char)  

hello(entername())   # <- this chains the function calls
                     # and is equivalent to
                     # name = entername()    # not the same 'name' variable as inside the entername() function, these are different scopes 
                     # hello(name)
```

Another option would be to use `global` variables, but you'd rather avoid this antipattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
def entername():
    name = input("Please enter your name: ")
    return name

name = entername()
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use the same "name" variable from different functions you have to define in globally.
Here, we define our variable inside the global scope and force functions to use the global variable instead of defining their own local variables.

```
import sys, time

name=''

def entername( ):
    global name
    name = input("Please enter your name: ")
    return

def hello():
    global name
    text = "Hello " + name + ", welcome to the simulator..."
    for char in text:
        sys.stdout.write(char)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        char, time.sleep(0.1)
    print(char)  
    return

entername()
hello()
```